# MassTransit3 message forwarding

Tags: masstransit

I have a message consumer (`IConsumer<>`) that acting like a message router. To route message I use `context.Forward()` method. But forwarding itself doesn't happening. RabbitClient throws:

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException**: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=406, text="PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'auto_delete' for exchange 'query1' in vhost 'Gateways': received 'false' but current is 'true'", classId=40, methodId=10, cause=
```

Yes, I'm trying to forward message to the queue that has been created with `auto_delete=true` flag. How can I forward messages to such endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To forward to an auto-delete exchange, you need to add some additional parameters to the query string before you pass it to the `GetSendEndpoint` method.

```
rabbitmq://server/exchange_name?autodelete=true
```

You can't forward directly to queues, so the `durable=true` should not be required, but if you continue to get an error, you can add `&durable=true` as well to resolve it.

Comment: What if I don't have knowledge about the arguments with which exchange was created? I just want to route message to exchange by its exchange_name. I guess I can't use forwarding like that?

Comment: If you're using forward, you should have some internal knowledge about the underlying system. Otherwise, there are much more explicit approaches to achieving your goals that won't be confusing when other engineers look at your code.